# email validation on focusout and tab

Tags: jquery, regex

please help me that how to achieve it.

I have a input field.

```
<input name="email" id="email_id" />
```

I have to apply email validation on focusout and using tab key. if email is not in proper format then focus does not lost from input field if focus lost by tab key .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to it. I think that it solve your problem.

```
var validate_email = function(email){
  var pattern = /^([a-zA-A0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
  var is_email_valid = false;
  if(email.match(pattern) != null){
    is_email_valid = true;
  }
  return is_email_valid;
}

$(document).on("keyup", "#email_id", function(event){
  var keypressed = event.which;
  var input_val = $(this).val();
  var is_success = true;
  if(keypressed == 9){
    is_success = validate_email(input_val);   
    if(!is_success){
      $(this).focus();
    }
  }
});

$(document).on("focusout", "#email_id", function(){
  var input_val = $(this).val();
  var is_success = validate_email(input_val); 

  if(!is_success){
    $("#email_id").focus();
  }
});
```